# Disable auto zoom in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have made a android application where I am showing current location of a user.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (currLocationMarker != null) {

        currLocationMarker.remove();
    }

     //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()) , 6.0f) );
}
```

It gives me my current location with marker but problem is whenever I try to zoom out from the current location, within some seconds it focused again to the same location (Current) so I am not able to see my other points (Markers) on the map.

How to disable this auto zoom in feature in Google Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center the camera on the current location only the first time:

```
private boolean firstLoad = true;
```

On your `onLocationChanged`:

```
if (firstLoad) {
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()) , 6.0f) );
    firstLoad = false;
}
```

Comment: But if I remove It will not be focused on the current location..What I want is when map gets loaded It should show the current location with the required zoom but when user do zoom out it should not take back to the location automatically

Comment: Answer updated to center the camera only the first time

Answer (score 1):

you should use the animateCamera method for the first time only. You can use a boolean to call it once only. Declare a boolean globally and make it false and once this method is called turn it to true, before calling this cameraAnimate method check if the boolean was false then only to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global boolean flag

```
boolean isFisrtTime = true;
```

replace

```
mGoogleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()) , 6.0f) );
```

with

```
if(isFisrtTime){
     mGoogleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()) , 6.0f) );
     isFisrtTime = false; //this is will work at start only
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your code called on `onMapReady` method? 
If not consider moving it there.
I think you are calling `animateCamera` in `onLocationChanged` and the code is called every time the location is updated and the map is re-focused to your location.